Session returns null when working Laravel and Vue js
I am working with Laravel and Vue js, after logging the user data stores in session correctly. Before I want to store any data, I first want to get the data from the session and according to the data, some event occurs. But the session returns null, nothing is in the session.
First, the data is saved in a session. After passing the data in view, the data is saved in local storage. It works properly when the system is offline, but it does not work after hosting it.
Below is the login function in the controller
  public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'password' => 'required',
            'device_name' => 'required',
        ]);
    
        $user = User::where('email', $request->email)->first();
   
        if (! $user || ! Hash::check($request->password, $user->password)) {
        
            throw ValidationException::withMessages([
                'email' => ['The provided credentials are incorrect.'],
            ]);
        }
        
        session()->put('user', $user);
        $user_info = session()->get('user');

        $arr = array(
            "user" => $user_info,
            "token" => $user->createToken($request->device_name)->plainTextToken
        );
        
        return $arr;
    }


It returns the array data correctly and also the session returns correct data.
After I want to get data from another function, the session returns null.
Below is the function which I want to get notification according to the logged in user. But the session returns nothing.
   public function getNotifications()
    {
        $user_info = session()->get('user');
        $notifications = RequestNotifications::where('notifiable_id' , $user_info->u_id)->orderBy('created_at' , 'DESC')->limit(10)->get();
        return response()->json($notifications);
    }

It returns the below message
message": "Attempt to read property "u_id" on null
Guide me, please!

Is this a JS problem or a PHP problem? What have you tried to resolve it? Where are you stuck?

From where do you call the other function? A job by any chance?

i believe there is a diffrent syntax for the shorthand session() and the $request->session() to keep the syntax relatively the same use $request-> before the current sessions or you use the shorthand and to get the data use session('user) and to set the data session(["user" => $user]) please tell me if this resolves your question so there can be an official answer made

it works properly when the system is offline but after hosting it does not work and returns null

I think it is a PHP problem because the session is in a controller function.

Why are you not using the laravel's attempt function for login? why is the reason are you trying to use
session('user', $user)

Laravel has a fully documented authentication system for that cases, if you're doing a custom login you can use the attempt function.
[https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/authentication#authenticating-users][1]
Accord to your sample, you only need to do
Auth::attempt($credentials);

Or if you want to login the user, you can use
Auth::login($user);

That's in case you want to use cookie's login, but I saw that you're using sanctum, because you're generating token, in that case, you don't need to save nothing in session, when you wrap your code in sanctum middleware, you can use
Auth::user() 

And that will bring you your current user model.

The problem is not with the login function; the function works correctly. First, the data is saved in a session. After passing the data in view, the data is saved in local storage. It works properly when the system is offline, but it does not work after hosting it.

Which part doesn't work? ..... if you're using sanctum, you don't need to use session, because its works different, maybe you need to share us more info about your workaround.

I don't use sanctum. After passing the data from the login function in the controller, by using the below code in login.vue page the data are stored in local storage for using them in vue components.
axios
.post("api/users/login", this.formData)
.then((response) => {
sessionStorage.setItem("token", response.data['token']);
sessionStorage.setItem("loggedInUserInfo", JSON.stringify(response.data['user']));
})
The system works properly in offline mode, but after hosting it does not work and the sessions become empty
